# How to access data stored in structure within array

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have an array which holds a structures which represents form fields of a web page. My question is how can I easily access data in the array to get the value I am looking for. In this case I am trying to get the value for the field with the name "availableScreensCSV" for now I am looping thru the array and if the key = "name' and is "availableScreensCSV" then I get the data for the value. I hope there is a simpler way to do this. Below is what my array / structure looks like

```
array

1   struct 
    NAME    templateId
    TYPE    hidden
    VALUE   [empty string]

2   struct
    NAME    useTestSystem
    TYPE    hidden
    VALUE   false

3   struct
    NAME    availableScreensCSV
    TYPE    hidden
    VALUE   ICASR,ICADM,ICTQ1,ICTQA,ICTQB,ICTQ6,ICFGB

4   struct
    NAME    ccna
    TYPE    hidden
    VALUE   IFX

5   struct
    NAME    pon
    TYPE    hidden
    VALUE   I11192014013

6   struct
    NAME    asr
    TYPE    hidden
    VALUE   1432310020

7   struct
    NAME    icsc
    TYPE    hidden
    VALUE   SW80
```

Comment: Can you post a straight screenshot of the output of `<cfdump var="#form#">`?

Answer (score 6):

My gut reaction is, "how did your data get into that array?" If it's a form post, you should be able to simply get form fields by name: `form.availableScreensCSV` -- but that hinges on your form post.

Since you neglected to mention, I'm assuming that the array **may not** always be in the same order, in which case looping is your only reasonable option. There are functional approaches like `arrayFind` with an inline function but that is some syntactic sugar on top of a loop. If you're just looking for cleaner, more readable code, then arrayFind with an inline function may be the way to go.

If you're looking for the most performant option, then a simple loop that does a `<cfbreak />` once it finds the desired element will be the best option.

Comment: no, that will not work, since I do not post the form so I don't get access to form stuff. I am getting an html page from a remote side and use jsoup to parse all input fields in to an array wich holds the structures. Each structure has a name, type and value field

Comment: The fact that you're using jsoup to parse a page is a pretty important part of your problem, you should have included it in the question. Nevertheless, my 2nd and 3rd paragraphs are still applicable and correct.

Comment: Adam is on track here. Unless your array length is in the hundreds there's no real appreciable penalty to looping  here. You've already paid the penalty by retrieving and parsing the html :)

Comment: If you are sticking with arrays, then Adam's suggestion is the correct one. However, as mentioned on your other thread, *how* you store the elements is up to you. Generally, arrays are preferred when you need to maintain a specific "order". However, if accessing the elements by name in more important, then a structure-of-structures is probably the better approach. If you choose the latter, be sure to account for multiple form fields with the same name.

Comment: .. Have you tried using a structure-of-structures instead of an array-of-structures?